# How do members of the SuperUser community coordinate to close a question?

Tags: discussion

I'm really curious as to how SuperUser community members, with the proper reputation, coordinate to vote and close a question. It seems like they are closed so fast I don't even have time to defend it. Are they litteraly pinging each other to close a specific question or do they have something they are montioring?

Comment: I'm an addict who reads every single new question if I can. I guess it's the same for the others :)

Comment: What you should really be asking is "how do superuser community members coordinate to reopen questions"

Comment: At your current reputation level, you can't even see pending votes to close your question. So how would you want to defend it?

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's no real 'coordination' to close questions. There *is* however a tab in the review page for questions with votes to close and a vote to close chatroom.

On the other hand, it takes 5 votes to close a question, and any >3000 vote user can do so. It just tends to happen on its own.

On the other hand  if you felt a question was closed, but shouldn't have, take a look around meta, work out a compelling arguement and post it here.There's [4 pages of these questions](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=reopen) (as of the time this question was rewritten) and if you can convince people to reopen it, there's less of a chance it'll be closed.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways. Some I can think of:

- The question happens to attract enough views on the front page and is subsequently closed
- The question is `flagged` by a user and the flag is handled by a moderator (or other 3k users who add their vote)
- The question is posted in a chat room, which will give it more exposure.
- Users with 10k reputation have special tools available to check existing close votes and follow up on that
- Users have review privileges and are allowed to see a list of questions that are about to be closed and add their vote

In your concrete case, the question had a flag sitting on it and was discussed on chat, which would have migrated it pretty fast. In fact, the community is quite fast when it comes to migrating questions that seem to fit better elsewhere.

Let me say though that there's nobody insisting that a question should be closed. Even though you can bring attention to it, five users (or one moderator) actually have to agree that it should be closed. And even then, it can be reopened.

If you have trouble understanding what flagging is, how moderators do their work, and what privileges are, please read our FAQ more carefully. Also, check out the FAQ on Meta Stack Overflow: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Here are the chat messages related to your question: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4962804#4962804

Answer (score 2):

There is [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117/super-user-vote-to-close-delete) for this, but most of the time we just see the questions. Feel free to comment, or post here, or flag for moderator attention if you think that the post has closed unfairly.

Comment: By posting here you mean referencing the link to my question in a comment to this question? So if I click the flag icon it will bring to a moderators attention who will then comment back? Who are the moderators?

Comment: In order: I mean a post saying something like "what was *insert link here* closed as .... Yes, that is what flagging is for, the current moderators are: http://meta.superuser.com/users/4377/sathya http://meta.superuser.com/users/307/random http://meta.superuser.com/users/1548/ivo-flipse http://meta.superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack http://meta.superuser.com/users/39366/dma57361 http://meta.superuser.com/users/2553/troggy

Comment: Your question was reopened @daniellopez46.

Comment: @soandos: You might want to link to the bottom of [this page](http://www.superuser.com/about), for instance, you forgot nhinkle. :)

Comment: @TomWijsman, thanks, I knew that page was somewhere, but could not find it.